# How do I get rid of "..." on medium.com?

Tags: medium

On medium.com, you can insert three dots between paragraphs. Example (from [here](https://blog.medium.com/tips-and-tricks-for-medium-writers-1d79498101c3#.37vppjju9)):

[image: three dots]

In my post, I added them and now I can't get rid of them. How do I select them to delete them?

Answer (score 3):

Just put your cursor directly above the line with the three dots and  hit the delete button. It seems to me that removing those three dots is equal to removing an image.